# string comparison doesnt work In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

My string comparison doesnt work.I tried compare,equals ,= and all of these methods doesnt work.
Here's my code:

```
Dim activeChild2 = Me.ActiveMdiChild
    If TypeOf activeChild2 Is Window Then
        Dim activeChild As Window = Me.ActiveMdiChild
        If (Not activeChild Is Nothing) Then
            If activeChild.CTR_User.ToString = activeChild.User_name.ToString Then
                Call activeChild.Edition()

                Select Case Trim$(UCase(activeChild.Name))
                    Case "FRM_MISSION"
                      'treatment
                    Case "FRM_TACHE"
                        'treatment

                End Select
            Else
                MsgBox("Error modification!!!!", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

The problem is in  If activeChild.CTR_User.ToString = activeChild.User_name.ToString Then .In spite of having same string toto=toto the code always fires to the else clause and show me the msgbox

Regards

Comment: If `activeChild.CTRL_User` and `activeChild.User_name` are both strings, then you don't need the `ToString` on either of them to do the comparison. If they are not strings, the results of `ToString` will almost always not match.

Comment: Yes you're right so what's the solution to compare an object and a string? CTR_user is an object  and the user_name is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you calling .ToString? Are activeChild.CTR_User and activeChild.User_name strings, or are they objects that you're trying to compare?

If they're objects, you can't compare them with .ToString(), as it will be inaccurate. you should use something like `activeChild.CTR_User.Equals(activeChild.User_name)` or `activeChild.CTR_User is activeChild.User_name`. I can't really give you specifics unless I know what types you're working with.

Have you tried putting a breakpoint on it and checking the values manually within Visual Studio's many debugging tools?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it helped me to figure out the problem.
In fact the CTR_user is an object (that i will affect a textbox in a treatment ) and the user_name is a string so its not possible to compare their values?
I debugged manually and i found same values in both variabl("admin"="admin") for example

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

try instead of **=** operator use **Like**

example:
If activeChild.CTR_User.ToString Like activeChild.User_name.ToString